# Force refresh on ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm working on C#, I have a project using a ListView.

I will try to summarize my case:

There is my ListView (I removed some parts):

```
<ListView x:Name="listItem">
    <ListView.View >
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Image" Width="268" x:Name="scoreGridItem" >
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="scoreIndicator">
                                    <Rectangle.Width>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource scoreConv}">
                                            <Binding Path="Score" />
                                            <Binding Path="Min" />
                                            <Binding Path="Max" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Rectangle.Width>
                                </Rectangle>

                                <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="40" Width="40" >
                                    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="{Binding BorderColor2}">
                                        <Image Width="38" Height="38" Source="{Binding Picture}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The list has a custom class in source :

```
public class ControlItem
{
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public BitmapSource Picture { get; set; }
}
```

When I add a new item in my view, I load a default `Picture`. A thread starts, and when it's over, I change value for `Index`. Then I want to change the `Picture` but the image in listview does not change.

How can I force the refresh ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ControlItem** should implement the interface **INotifyPropertyChanged**.
And your property has to call a **OnPropertyChanged** event.

```
public class ControlItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged;
    private BitmapSource picture;

    public int Score { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public BitmapSource Picture
    {
       get { return picture; }
       set 
           {
               picture = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```